# Integral $\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{x}_{0}x.e^{-x^2/y} \, dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This question was asked a couple of times in my Engineering Maths exam in last 5 years but strangely I couldn't find any solution of it on the Internet by Googling, as far as I have tried.

Solve by changing the order of integration:
$$\int^{\infty}_{0} \int^{x}_{0}x.e^{-x^2/y} \, dy\,dx$$

Region of area on the graph should look like following I think.

[image]

If I am not wrong the this should be the new order: $$\int^{y}_{0} \int^{x}_{0}x.e^{-x^2/y} \, dy\,dx$$
Upon trying, I am encountering endless integration. Could anyone help how we will reach the solution. Online calculators aren't giving any solution (error or not solvable kind of thing)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For the "new order" did you mean $\int_0^\color{red}\infty\dots dx$?

Comment: J. W. Tanner, aah my bad, I was wrong in calculating limit. My bad. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{x} xe^{-x^{2}/y} dydx=\int_0^{\infty} \int_y^{\infty} xe^{-x^{2}/y}dx dy$. This becomes $\int_0^{\infty} -\frac y 2 e^{-x^{2}/y}|_y^{\infty} dx=\frac 1  2\int_0^{\infty} ye^{-y}dy=\frac 1  2$.

Answer (score 1):

Check your limits -- when you swap the order of integration, it should give
$$\int_0^\infty\int_y^\infty xe^{-\frac{x^2}y}\,dx\, dy$$
from which it should be a straightforward integral.